# how to add only one point on collision without destroying the collided object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

When I don't destroy the object, the points just keep adding until I move the player. How do I fix this? I don't want to disable the collider either.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision hit)
{
   if (hit.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
   {
     score++;
   }
}
```

Comment: would it help if I'd tell you to use OnCollisionExit and 1 bool between those?

Answer (score 0):

This question needs more context of what is going on in Unity, but looks to me like what you would want to do is use a HashSet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8

That `HashSet<GameObject>` would be an attribute of your script and you would add the hit.gameobject to it. Every time you get a OnCollisionEnter you would do a `Contains()` on the HashSet, if the object is not there, you add it and increment the score, if the object is already there, then you do nothig.